# Can't see data from MySQL into fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

**EDIT**

Is it possible to send the json data into this part:

```
 $.each( res, function(key, row)(
        {
        events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: //from AJAX row['name'],
          backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
          borderColor: "#f56954" //red
        },
...
```

I am trying to add data from MysQL into `fullcalendar`.

Here is my fullcalendar script:

```
     <script>
        (function ($) { 
            $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
          },
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: {
              url: 'fullcalendar/get-events.php',
              //url: 'fullcalendar/myfeed.php',
              error: function() {
                  $('#script-warning').show();
              }
          },
          loading: function(bool) {
              $('#loading').toggle(bool);
          }
      });

  });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Where I get values from `get-events.php`, and here is the code:

```
<?php
//Set error reporting on
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//Include connection file
require_once('global.php');

//Json and PHP header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$events = array();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$id_logged = $_SESSION['login_id'];

    $search_date = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE id_logged = :id_logged";
    $search_date_stmt = $conn->prepare($search_date);
    $search_date_stmt->bindValue(':id_logged', $id_logged);
    $search_date_stmt->execute();
    $search_date_stmt_fetch = $search_date_stmt->fetchAll();
    $search_date_stmt_count = $search_date_stmt->rowCount();

    $i = 0;
    foreach($search_date_stmt_fetch as $row)
    {
        $events[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }

    echo json_encode($events);
?>
```

The result is show properly at the XHR:

[image]

[image]

But I can't see any of them in the calendar:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any error in your console ?

Comment: nope, no errors at the console

Comment: Just read this : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/. You must return a feed with the properties like `start` or `end`.

Comment: I saw it but didn't figure out how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Build your response like the doc said :

```
$search_date_stmt_fetch = $search_date_stmt->fetchAll();
$search_date_stmt_count = $search_date_stmt->rowCount();

foreach($search_date_stmt_fetch as $row)
{
    $events[] = array(
       'start' => $row->your_date_start,
       'end'   => $row->your_date_end,
       'id'    => $row->your_id
       ...);
}

echo json_encode($events);
```

See the doc to know the properties you need : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/